# Port sharing using Http.sys in Azure service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Want to host 2 asp .net core 2 websites in Azure service fabric which use port 80. In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#bring-your-own-protocol) they mentions port sharing but not sure how to configure this? is there a way to mention host name?

Answer (score 1):

Use this class:

```
public class HttpSysInstanceListener
{

    public static ServiceInstanceListener[] CreateListener(Type startupType, string endpointName, string rootPath, int port)
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new HttpSysCommunicationListener(serviceContext, $"{endpointName}", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    return new WebHostBuilder()

                        .UseHttpSys(options =>
                        {
                            options.UrlPrefixes.Add($"http://+:{port}/{rootPath}/");
                            options.Authentication.Schemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                            options.MaxConnections = null;
                        })
                        .ConfigureServices(services => services
                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext)                               
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseStartup(startupType)
                        .UseUrls(url)
                        .UseApplicationInsights()
                        .Build();
                }))
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a .NET CORE stateless WEB Service API then use HttpSys. However,        HttpsSys can be only used with IIS and not KESTREL.

To use HttpSys in a stateless service, override the CreateServiceInstanceListeners method and return a HttpSysCommunicationListener instance:
C#

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new HttpSysCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseHttpSys()
                    .ConfigureServices(
                        services => services
                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls(url)
                    .Build()))
    };
}
```

also change url to something different than the default:

```
.UseUrls(url+="WebService")
```

so for a localhost on port 80 the URL would be:

http(s)//localhost.com/**WebService**/api/foo

[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#httpsys-in-reliable-services)